# i want to install AMD Radeon HD 7670M on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, ati, vga

I have ubuntu 13.04 and i want to install the AMD Radeon HD 7670M driver on it

my laptop is heated when using ubuntu , and battery drained fast

i guess the problem is with my VGA card because that doesn't happen on windows

Answer (score 0):

There are two options I know: 
1.  that you disable your graphic card from BIOS and your pc/laptop will use the Intel hd400 graphics and it will not heat up. 
2.  if i am not mistaking you have Hp ProBook 4540s with discrete graphic card if yes then goto the 
 link [Linux Drivers for ProBook 4540s](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=5229457&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=5229455&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=2020),
download the driver for Graphic Card from the link that file will be of `.tar` Extract it and then convert the `.rpm` file into `.deb` you can do this by alien command and you will be ready to install it.

after installing those you will still have the heat issue because Linux/Ubuntu does not support switchable graphic card yet i guess, or its really challenging. So i would suggest you option 1 until you find a way to install the switchable Radeon Graphics.

Comment: No, I have Dell inspiron n5520